# Wildcard return type in Typescript where objects that implement an interface are returned

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following interface that I use in an `abstract` base class:

```
interface MyInterface {
   field1: string
}

abstract class BaseClass {
   // some fields here...
   abstract serialize(): Array<MyInterface>
}
```

I now have a several subclasses that extend from `BaseClass` that each contain a couple of additional fields that are different per subclass. E.g.

```
class Subclass1 extends BaseClass {
   // some additional fields that are not in BaseClass
   serialize(): Array<MyInterface> {
      return [{field1: "test", field2: "test2"}];
   }
}
```

Now I am looking for the correct return type of the `serialize` function that should have the semantics of:

"**return any object that implements MyInterface, i.e. that has at least all fields from MyInterface, but it could also have more**"

In the above setup, Typescript is giving me an error because the return type does not conform to `MyInterface`. This also makes sense. `field2` is not in the interface.

I think I am looking for the Typescript equivalent of a Java unbounded wildcard. Sth. like

```
List<? extends MyInterface>
```

meaning anything that implements `MyInterface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to intersect `MyInterface` with the extra fields you want to return. Subclasses can refine their methods return types in this way so long as the return type still conforms to the base class.

```
class Subclass1 extends BaseClass {
   serialize(): Array<MyInterface & { field2: string }> {
      return [{field1: "test", field2: "test2"}]
   }
}

const foo = new Subclass1().serialize()
// (MyInterface & { field2: string })[]
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=40&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlSZgIAbAEwEYAuZAZzClAHMiBfIouAIxZREYZAkpwmTZACFJEAMISphEqQD065gHsAtinJVq0gBbQIAOitrkAoSObRgcSsABeEABQBKRgEEoYXQAHgxsSFhECAA+bl5xSWkAZQBXfgSpWmQIAA9IEGNZeSVE1VJkTR19W2pqYDBgbRAXZEMaaTATOFE4KBQQbVFQIqZFZSYbUbYXdy9fZACg0KwcSPwAMkJWihoAJkYhDmQuaLLy0j6wFKgQZABtAja6RgAiSBYXgBpto33kN4gLF2Ly4AF0bDweEQEE0WK1tNpkABeZAgCAAd2QqXS41oPgsU2crg8PiIlU8YVWeBQmwIPz2B1YRy43juoKAA)

---

Or if you want `BaseClass` to enforce this, you can make it generic, and have the extra props type merged there. This cleans things up a bit, and make it clear at the top level of the class what other data this class might deal with.

Now you can remove the return type annotation entirely since it's completely enforced by `BaseClass`.

```
interface MyInterface { field1: string }

abstract class BaseClass<Extra = Record<string, never>> {
   abstract serialize(): Array<MyInterface & Extra>
}

class Subclass1 extends BaseClass<{ field2: string }> {
   serialize() {
      return [{field1: "test", field2: "test2"}]
   }
}

const foo = new Subclass1().serialize()
// { field1: string, field2: string }[]
```

NOTE: `Record<string, never>` looks weird, but it basically means an empty object, which is a sensible default for this generic type parameter.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgb2RmAgBsATARgC5kBnMKUAc2QF8AoTuAI0aiIwyBGTj16yAELiIAYTESAPAFEAHkzjIAvMgBKEBAHsoFJQNYAaZCAgA3aAD5HhTsnd8BQhtGBwywABeEAAUAJR0AIJQguhKGNiQsIgoAGTI6pqOnFycouKSAMoArrz5ElTIEBoQIBSSMvTyivRKRCTkFABMdBYgbOwuBG7uTcz+QaFhru6zyFAQYMVQIMgA2gQdlLTIAESQjLvWW910+xCMXbvsALojHDncxiCMxEZGOjYQAO7IJWUtKjhAB0Yz8AWC4U4AHpoYRiKRtr0mFYEZ0egwUf0OGsbkA)

Answer (score 2):

You're not even returning an array in your example, which is your principle problem..

However, if you **directly** try to return the array:

```
return [{field1: "test", field2: "test2"}];
```

you will fall victim to [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). ([see also](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/typescript-excess-property-checks-6ffe5584f450)).

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error

It's actually perfectly acceptable to return something with a wider surface area that conforms to the return-type, but not if you create it on-the-spot. TypeScript takes the view that *if the only existing reference to an object has excess properties then they are there by mistake* because they become immediately inaccessible.

So... although I wouldn't recommend directly returning an object literal with properties that are non-retrivable unless you use type-assertions, you can sidestep by assigning an intermediate variable and return that instead.

```
// unuseful way of sidestepping
// excess property checks. bad idea.
const returnValue = [{field1: "test", field2: "test2"}];
return returnValue;
```

In all likelihood, in the real-world, the thing that you are trying to return is already stored in a variable or field and this problem stems from simplistic test/example code.

Manufacturing an object of the wrong shape specifically to return something that conforms to an interface with a narrower surface area smells of a mistake, so TypeScript actively tries to prevent it.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkZgIAbAEwEYAuZAZzClAHMiBfIouAEasoiMMgRU4zZsgBCUiAGFJ0wiTIB6DSwD2AWxQVqNGQAtoEAHTX1pQcNEtowOFWAAvCAAoAlEwCCUCLoADwY2JCwiBAAfDx8ElIyAMoArgKJ0nTIEAAekCAmcgrKSWpkyFq6BshwNDTAYMA6IK7klLQyYKZwYnBQKCA6YqDFzEoqzLZO7K4e3n7IgcFhWDhRSDHlFWQDYKlQIMgA2gTtxozIAESQrFcANOe0AExMNxCsz1fI3AC6ANzTXi8IiZFLpMHPHL5CCFGTycalVTECrjWZuTy+AJBOChcLrPCxbY7cQtVjIKDIAC8JzORlol3ed0e9Jor2utzAXx+AOmFT2ByOUEBFWBQA)

Comment: I think a simpler solution (after returning an array) is to remove the `Array<MyInterface>` return type specifier in the subclass. This will allow typescript to infer the return type

Comment: @smac89 The linting rules we use in my workplace specifically expect a return type on any exported member, so this wouldn't fly for me.

Comment: This is a not a great idea. That sidestep renders `field2` inaccessible. Since it's not part of the return type, there is no direct way to actually get that property. You'd have to do `Object.keys(obj)` or something to find it.

Comment: @AlexWayne This is why I stated *"In all likelihood, in the real-world, the thing that you are trying to return is already stored in a variable or field and this problem stems from simplistic test/example code."*. I frequently return an interface that is a subset of the actual returned object, but yes, in this simplistic example, the excess properties will be lost without a type-assertion, which smells bad (hence typescript complaining).